# Existence of solution for reflected SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have an equation of the form:

$$dX_t=\mu(X_t)X_tdt+\sigma(X_t)X_tdZ_t+dL_t, \quad X_0=x_0\in (0,a]$$

where, $L_t$ is the reflection function (as in Skorokhod, 1961). This reflection does not allow the process to get past a barrier $a>0$. Therefore, this process is always between 0 and $a$.

While I was able to find many results concerning the structure I must impose on the coefficients $\mu(\cdot)$ and $\sigma(\cdot)$ to get strong solutions, pathwise uniqueness, weak solutions and so on for processes without a reflecting barrier, I was unable to find much on processes with reflection.

Does anyone know a good reference for this kind of processes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficient conditions for strong existence and uniqueness of solutions to stochastic differential equations with reflection were derived by Dupuis & Ishii (see below for detailed reference) in the following cases:

1. the reflection direction is single-valued and varies smoothly, but the boundary of the domain may be nonsmooth; and,
2. the domain of the SDE is the intersection of a finite number of domains with relatively smooth boundary, and at the resulting corner points there may be more than one reflection direction.

**Reference**

Dupuis, Paul, and Hitoshi Ishii. [SDEs with oblique reflection on nonsmooth domains.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176989415) The Annals of Probability (1993): 554-580.

Comment: Thank you very much, again. I am still trying to understand that paper (and it has been hard given my poor training on stochastic calculus). If I understood correctly, to guarantee strong uniqueness Dupuis and Ishii assume a Lipschitz condition on the coefficients σ and μ (Corollary 5.2). Without the Lipschitz conditions (and under some other assumptions on the domain and the direction), there is a weak solution. That is already useful, but it would be nice to have a stronger result without the Lipschitz conditions (uniqueness in law, or pathwise uniqueness, for instance)

Comment: Can we resolve your previous question first?

Comment: I am sorry, I realized now it is a different question from my original one, which was more general. To keep things organized, I created a more specific question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249286/reflected-sde-with-non-lipschitz-coefficients